# Hls video player freeze when i switch level until get to the next fragment

Tags: javascript, hls.js, aws-media-convert

When I switch my quality level of my player with the prop (currentLevel) of hls.js, the video stays frozen until get to next fragment. The duration of each fragment are 10 seconds, so if I change the quality in the second 1 of the fragment, the video is freeze 9 seconds.

I'm using the library hls.js to play my .m3u8 file and i have obtained this file with aws media convert (Apple Hls output). When i play the demo video of hls.js library, the switching level is almost instant (not 9 seconds to wait like my video) https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/. I put the same configuration in demo player and my video. Because of this, i suspect that is a problem with the media convert, some property of configuration.

Someone with the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a most likely a player configuration issue, not a manifest issue or content issue. You can test this by playing each child rendition manifest directly using your player and/or ffplay. The browser dev tools window will show you the start and finish time for retrieving the manifests and segments. If the child renditions all play smoothly and correctly, then your manifests, content, server and network are all fine.

Gracefully switching between renditions is the player's responsibility.
Have a look at the player settings for how many segments of variant type XX are retrieved and cached before playback begins.

To improve player responsiveness, you may want to explore shorter segment durations which should retrieve and start more quickly.